# Sum of numbers under 10,000 that are multiples of 3, 5 or 7 in Java

Tags: java, sum

I know how to get the program to add up the sums of the multiple for each of 3, 5 and 7, but I'm not sure how I'd get the program to only use each number once. For example, I can get the program to find out all of the numbers and add them up for 3 and then do the same for 5, but then the number 15 would be in the final number twice. I'm not sure exactly how I'd get it to only take the number once. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use a `for` loop thus:

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i=1; i<10000; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i % 5 == 0 || i % 7 == 0)
        sum += i;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

While the generate-and-test approach is simple to understand, it is also not very efficient if you want to run this on larger numbers. Instead, we can use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

The idea is to first sum up too many numbers by looking at the multiples of 3, 5 and 7 separately. Then we subtract the ones we counted twice, i.e. multiples of 3*5, 3*7 and 5*7. But now we subtracted too much and need to add back the multiples of 3*5*7 again.

We start by finding the sum of all integers `1..n` which are multiples of `k`. First, we find out how many there are, `m = n / k`, rounded down thanks to integer division. Now we just need to sum up the sequence `k + 2*k + 3*k + ... + m*k`. We factor out the `k` and get `k * (1 + 2 + ... + m)`.

This is a well-known arithmetic series, which we know sums to `k * m * (m + 1)/2` (See [triangle number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)).

```
private long n = 9999;
private long multiples(long k) {
    long m = n / k;
    return k * m * (m + 1) / 2:
}
```

Now we just use inclusion-exclusion to get the final sum:

```
long sum = multiples(3) + multiples(5) + multiples(7)
         - multiples(3*5) - multiples(3*7) - multiples(5*7)
         + multiples(3*5*7);
```

This will scale much better to larger `n` than just looping over all the values, but beware of overflow and change to `BigInteger`s if necessary.

Comment: +1 for using math rather than brute force. I racked my brain trying to figure out the `multiples` method on my own, and when I gave up I found that you'd already posted it.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: Threw in my derivation of `multiples`, just for you :)

Comment: and how do you generalize this, for q factors, i tried to think about it and my head exploded

Comment: @gia: To generalize this for q factors, you start by adding the multiples of each individual factor, then subtract the multiples of each pair of factors, then add back in each triple, subtract each quadruple, etc.. You alternate adding and subtracting until you get to the final q-tuple of all the factors. In other words, for each non-empty subset of factors, add it if the size of the subset is odd, or subtract it if the size of the subset is even.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html) to store the unique multiples, and then sum the values of the Set.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a [Set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html). This way you are guaranteed that you won't get any duplicates if they are your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be to add each number thats a multiple of 3,5, or 7 to an Answer list. And then as you work thru each number, make sure that its not already in the answer list.

(pseudo-code)

```
List<int> AnswerList;
List<int> MultiplesOfFive;
List<int> MultiplesOfSeven;
List<int> MultiplesOfThree;

for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000; i++)
{
  if ( i % 3 == 0 && AnswserList.Contains(i) == false)
  {
    MultiplesOfThree.Add(i); 
    AnswerList.Add(i);
  }
  if ( i % 5 == 0 && AnswserList.Contains(i) == false)
  {
    MultiplesOfFive.Add(i); 
    AnswerList.Add(i);
  }
  if ( i % 7 == 0 && AnswserList.Contains(i) == false)
  {
    MultiplesOfSeven.Add(i); 
    AnswerList.Add(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need to know the counts for each multiple prime, then the single for loop suggested by StriplingWarrior makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

for the solution that loops 1 to 1000 use i<=10000 otherwise it'll skip 10000 itself which is a multiple of 5. Apologies, for some reason i can't post this as a comment

Comment: The question asks to sum "numbers under 10,000", so 10,000 should be skipped based on the given specification.