# How to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

Not sure if I should've posted this on math.stackexchange instead, but it includes more programming so I posted it here.

The question seems really simple, but I've sat here for at least one hour now not figuring it out. I've tried different solutions, and read math formulas for it etc but it won't gives me the right answer when coding it! I made two different solutions for it, which both gives me the wrong answer. The first solution gives me 265334 while the second one gives me 232169. The answer is 233168, so the second solution is closer.

I should mention this is a question from [Project Euler, the first one](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=1) to be precise.

Here's my code. Any ideas what's wrong?

```
nums = [3, 5]
max = 999

result = 0
for num in nums:
    for i in range(1,max):
        if num*i < max:
            result += num*i
print result


result = 0
for i in range(0,max):
    if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0:
        result += i

print result
```

Comment: One of your answers is right.

Comment: Definitely doesn't belong on math stack exchange it is a variation on a (somewhat famous) programming interview question called fizz buzz.

Comment: I just answered a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5929346/sum-of-numbers-under-10-000-that-are-multiples-of-3-5-or-7-in-java/5929592#5929592). The code's in Java, but should be easily translated to Python.

Comment: your solution is O(n), this can be easily solved in O(1) time.

Comment: [`sum [3,6..999] + sum [5,10..999] - sum [15,30..999]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11985751/849891)

Comment: From Project Euler: We hope that you enjoyed solving this problem. Please do not deprive others of going through the same process by publishing your solution outside Project Euler. If you want to share your insights then please go to thread 1 in the discussion forum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`range(k,max)` does not include `max`, so you're really checking up to and including 998 (while 999 is a multiple of 3). Use `range(1,1000)` instead.

Comment: Oh god this is embarassing! I had it at 1000 before, but i changed it. Oh well, thanks! :)

Answer (score 18):

You are overcomplicating things. You just need a list of numbers that are multiples of 3 or 5 which you can get easily with a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0]
```

Then use [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum) to get the total:

```
>>> sum([i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0])
<<< 233168
```

Or even better use a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) instead:

```
>>> sum(i for i in range(1000) if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0)
```

Or even *better* better (courtesy Exelian):

```
>>> sum(set(list(range(0, 1000, 3)) + list(range(0, 1000, 5))))
```

Comment: I'm new to python so i didn't even know you could do it like this, and tbh i still don't quite get it. I'll look into it, thanks!

Comment: You should [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) are great :D

Comment: In cases like this, generator expressions are even better: `sum(i for i in xrange(1,1000) if (i%3 == 0) or (i%5 == 0))`, then neither of the arrays has to be created. Not that you'll notice any difference for 1000, but sometimes creating huge great lists is worth avoiding.

Comment: I daresay you still make it too complicated. Try this: `sum(set(range(0, 1000, 3) + range(0, 1000, 5)))`

Answer (score 3):

I like this the most:

```
def divisibles(below, *divisors):
    return (n for n in xrange(below) if 0 in (n % d for d in divisors))

print sum(divisibles(1000, 3, 5))
```

Comment: I quite like `any(n % d == 0 for d in divisors)`, presumably it does pretty much the same work though so it's purely an aesthetic difference.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your first solution is that it double-counts multiples of 15 (because they are multiples of both 3 and 5).

The problem with your second solution is that it doesn't count 999 (a multiple of 3). Just set `max = 1000` to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

```
result = 0
for i in range(0,1000):
    if (i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 == 0):
        print i
        result = result + i
print result
```

Output:

```
0
3
5
6
9
.
.
.
993
995
996
999
233168
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is from 6 years ago but I just thought id share a solution that found from a math formula that I thought was interesting as it removes the need to loop through all the numbers.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/9305

```
def sum_of_two_multiples(nums, maxN):
    "takes tuple returns multiples under maxN (max number - 1)"
    n1, n2 = nums = nums[:2]
    maxN -= 1
    def k(maxN, kx):
        n = int(maxN / kx)
        return int(kx * (0.5 * n * (n+1)))

return sum([k(maxN, n) for n in nums]) - k(maxN, n1*n2)
```

Outputs the follows

```
print(sum_of_two_multiples((3,5), 10))
# 23
print(sum_of_two_multiples((3,5), 1000))
# 233168
print(sum_of_two_multiples((3,5), 10**12))
# 233333333333166658682880
```

Answer (score 1):

```
max = 1000  # notice this here
result = 0
for i in range(0,max):
if i%3 == 0 or i%5 == 0:
    result += i

print result
```

This works, but use 1000 for max, so it includes 999 too.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was 3 months ago but as an experiment because I am new to python I decided to try and combine some of the other people answers and I came up with a method you can pass the max number to and the divisors as a list and it returns the sum:

```
def sum_of_divisors(below, divisors):
    return sum((n for n in xrange(below) if 0 in (n % d for d in divisors)))

max = 1000
nums = [3, 5]

print sum_of_divisors(max, nums)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are floor(999/3) multiples of 3, floor(999/5) multiples of 5, and floor(999/15) multiples of 15 under 1000.

For 3, these are: 3 + 6 + 9 + 12 +... + 999 = 3 * (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +...+333)

= 3 * (333 * 334 / 2) because the sum of the integers from 1 to k is k*(k+1)/2.

Use the same logic for the sum of multiples of 5 and 15. This gives a constant time solution. Generalize this for arbitrary inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think only the last few lines from your code are important.
The or statement is the key statement in this code.
Also rater than setting the max value to 999, you should set it to 1000 so that it will cover all values.
Here is my code.

```
    ans=0
    for i in range(1,1000):
        if(i%3==0 or i%5==0):
            ans += i
    print(ans)
    input('press enter key to continue');#this line is only so that the screen stays until you press a key
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t = int(input())
for a in range(t):
n = int(input().strip())
sum=0
for i in range(0,n):
       if i%3==0 or i%5==0:
            sum=sum+i
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 1):

total = 0

maxrange = input("Enter the maximum range") #Get the maximum range from the keyboard
print("")

max = int(maxrange)

for i in range (0,max):
if i%3 == 0 or i%5 ==0:
total = total +i

print (total)

Comment: You should place code in code blocks and explain what your code does to improve your answer.

Comment: Hey @OwenIT. Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be great if you could format your answer - it really helps with readability. If you can explain your answer that would be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use functional programming tools (*filter*):

```
def f(x):
    return x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0
    filter(f, range(1,1000)) 
print(x)
```

Or use two lists with subtraction of multiples of 15 (which appears in both lists):

```
sum1 = []
for i in range(0,1000,3):
    sum1.append(i)
sum2 = []
for n in range(0,1000,5):
    sum2.append(n)
del sum2[::3] #delete every 3-rd element in list
print(sum((sum1)+(sum2)))
```

I like this solution but I guess it needs some improvements...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
count = 1000
m = [3, 5, 3*5]
result = 0
Sum = 0
for j in m:
    result = 0
    for i in range(count):
        if i*j < 1000:
            result = result + i*j
        elif i == (count - 1):
            if j < 15:
                Sum = result + Sum
            elif j == 15:
                Sum = Sum - result
                print(Sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution:

```
for n in range(100):
    if n % 5==0:
        if n % 3==0:
        print n, "Multiple of both 3 and 5"    #if the number is a multiple of 5, is it a multiple of 3? if yes it has has both.

    elif n % 5==0:
        print n, "Multiple of 5"

    elif n % 3==0:
        print n, "Multiple of 3"

    else:
        print n  "No multiples"
```

Comment: OP asked what was wrong in his code, not for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

this is my solution

```
sum = 0
for i in range (1,1000):
        if (i%3)==0 or (i%5)==0:
            sum = sum + i
print(sum)
```

Comment: This is low quality and it is to be only a comment. Once you have enough reputation you can write comments

Answer (score 0):

```
count = 0

for i in range(0,1000):
    if i % 3 == 0 or i % 5 ==0:
        count = count + i

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it was 7 years ago but I wanna share my solution to this problem.

```
x= set()
for i in range(1,1001):
    if (i % 3) == 0:
        x.add(i)

for j in range(1,1001):
    if (j % 5) == 0:
        x.add(j)

print(sum(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do it in range 1 , 100

This is how I did it.

```
For i in range(1,100):

If i ÷ 3 == 0 and i ÷ 5 == 0:

 print(i)
```

So with 1000 you just change the 100 to 1000

I had to find the multiples of 3 and 5 within 100 so if you need 3 or 5 just change it to or  and it will give you more answers too. I'm just starting to learn so correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This is not actually an answer to the original question, it prints all the numbers which are multiples of 3 and 5. The question is asking how to sum them. :-)