# Project Euler #1 using Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
import Data.Set

euler :: Int
euler = sum [ x | x <- nums ]
    where
    nums = Data.Set.toList (Data.Set.union (Data.Set.fromList [3,6..999])
                                           (Data.Set.fromList [5,10..999]))
```

I am learning Haskell and hope you don't mind me asking this. Is there a nicer way to get a list holding all natural numbers below one thousand that are multiples of 3 or 5? (E.g. with zip or map?)

Edit:

```
import Data.List

euler :: Int
euler = sum (union [3,6..999] [5,10..999])
```

Thanks for your help, guys.

Comment: [data-ordlist:Data.List.Ordered.union](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/data-ordlist/0.4.5/doc/html/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:union); also, `[x | x <- nums]` is better spelled `nums`.

Comment: First it looked ugly, now I feel stupid... euler = sum (union [3,6..999] [5,10..999]) works. Thanks, guys.

Comment: No, `Data.List.union` is inefficient, of quadratic time complexity.

Answer (score 15):

Use list comprehension:

```
sum [x | x <- [1..999], x `mod` 3 == 0 || x `mod` 5 == 0]
```

Comment: sum [n | n <- [0..999], m <- [3,5], n `mod` m == 0]  - (may be a bit nicer/shorter)

Comment: @ses - if this what you meant? this compiled: sum [n | n <- [1..999], m <- [3,5], n `mod` m == 0]  but wrong answer due to the condition where the number is a multiple of 3 and 5 eg 15.  I like your thinking. Ahh the ' is missing in this interface around the mod

Answer (score 10):

You could go with the hardcoded version too:

```
sum $ [3, 6 .. 999] ++ [5, 10 .. 999] ++ [-15, -30 .. -999]
```

Comment: double-plus-good, if you ask me! [Inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) in action.

Comment: or the slightly less hardcoded: `solve a b n = sum $ [a, a*2 .. n] ++ [b, b*2 .. n] ++ [-(a*b), -(a*b*2) .. -n]`

Comment: Clever, but excessively complex for the simple problem at hand.

Comment: it's the less complex solution programming wise. Maths wise it's simple too.

Answer (score 8):

This will give you the list you asked for:

```
filter (\x -> (x `mod` 3 == 0) || (x `mod` 5 == 0)) [1..999]
```

Comment: (You had ' instead of ` for the inline functions.)

Answer (score 5):

Here's one.

```
mults35 = union [3,6..999] [5,10..999]
  where
    union (x:xs) (y:ys) = case (compare x y) of 
       LT -> x : union  xs  (y:ys)
       EQ -> x : union  xs     ys 
       GT -> y : union (x:xs)  ys
    union  xs     []    = xs
    union  []     ys    = ys
```

Here's another, less efficient way:

```
import Data.List

nub . sort $ ([3,6..999] ++ [5,10..999])
```

(we don't have to use fully qualified names if we have the import statement).

Also interesting is to find the multiples of *only* 3 and 5:

```
m35 = 1 : (map (3*) m35 `union` map (5*) m35)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sum [x | x <- [1..999], let m k = (x`mod`k==0), m 3 || m 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution for a list of numbers instead of just 3 and 5:

```
addMultiples :: [Int] ->  Int -> Int
addMultiples multiplesOf upTo = sum[n | n <- [1..upTo-1], or (map ((0==) . mod n) multiplesOf)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that is super-fast.  Try it with values of over a billion.

```
eu x = sum[div (n*(p*(p+1))) 2 | n<-[3,5,-15], let p = div (x-1) n]
```

I imagine it can be shortened further.