# How to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000?

Tags: python, python-3.x

It supposed to be done with a For loop but what i tried won't work. 
When I run the programme using , it displays:

```
0
5
<snip ...>
97515
98505
99500
100500
```

Please help:

```
num = int(input("Do you want to see multiples of 3 or 5 added?: "))
num_1 = 0

for counter in range (0,1000 + 1, num):
    num_1 = num_1 + counter
    print (num_1)
```

Comment: Could you be more specific than *"won't work"*?

Comment: you certainly want to unindent the `print` statement so you only get the final result.

Comment: I see neither 3 nor 5 in that code...

Comment: @NiklasB. it looks like it takes it as input then uses that as the step value for a range.

Comment: Have you tried to do the part that requires you to get the multiples of 3 and 5? Can you show that part of your code as well? Maybe you were close with your implementation and just need a hint?

Comment: @idjaw don't bother: the problem is just an indentation problem with print: it prints all the iterations whereas it should only print the final result.

Comment: And what did you expect instead? Note that indentation matters in Python.

Comment: Thank you, it is working now.

Comment: Someone found Project Euler! (Sort of?)

Comment: @JordanMcQueen project euler is excellent to teach oneself python: at least you're working on some interesting problems instead of printing list of students or computing taxes.

Comment: The guy lifted it from project euler :) You should try it, it's really excellent.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes, I quite love Project Euler. I was just pointing it out. ;)

Comment: @JordanMcQueen I figured it out. I just wanted to emphasize that for others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930300/how-to-find-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to learn programming and want somebody to help. But please don't post your homework here and hope that somebody will give the correct. However, I will help you with the logic.

- For is used only when the number of iteration is fixed. In your case, it is not the number of iteration is fixed. Instead, it is the maximum value that is fixed (1000)
- Use IF to check if the value of the counter is a multiplication of 3 or 5 (use modulo (%) and an OR.
- If your program is correct, you should get 233168

Good luck with your study

Comment: One should add, write a unit test first for that last number.

Comment: It isn't actually homework but I understand what your saying, Thank you, I have got it working now.

Answer (score -1):

You almost got it right. 
Maybe this small example will guide you to how your code part can work.

For example:

```
num = int(input("Do you want to see multiples of 3 or 5 added?: "));
num_1 = 1;
maxNumber = 1000;

for counter in range(0, maxNumber):
    num_1 = num_1 * num;
    if num_1 > maxNumber:
        break;
    else:
        print(num_1);
```