# Sum of multiple of 3+5 < 100

Tags: python

New to Jupyter Notebook, computing this code to return sum of values that are a multiple of 3 and 5, AND less than 100 in my list range 1, 100. I've got a feeling that I'm truncating the code by removing 3 and 5 from the equation. Not sure how/where to include that.

```
print(list(range(1, 100)))
multiple35 = 0

for i in range (1, 100):
    if i % 15 == 0 and multiple35 <= 100:
        multiple35 += i
        print(multiple35)
```

My print line returns the range, Plus the 3 correct multiples less than 100. BUT ALSO prints 150, which is greater than and should be excluded from the result.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99]
15
45
90
150
```

Appreciate your help here.

Comment: is the sum not supposed to be higher than 100 or the range limit is 100?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the sum of all the multiples of 3 or 5 below 1000 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930300/how-to-find-the-sum-of-all-the-multiples-of-3-or-5-below-1000-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> BUT ALSO prints 150, which is greater than and should be excluded from the result.

The reason is simple. You are testing `multiple35 <= 100` *before* the addition (`multiple35 += i`). So the sum is printed first and then tested in the next round. Therefore the output ends *after* the first occurrence that is bigger than 100.

By the way, it is useless to go through all natural numbers and only do anything on each 15th element (because of `i % 15 == 0`). You can use a tailored range instead:

```
>>> list(range(15,100,15))
[15, 30, 45, 60, 75, 90]
```

So a simplified loop which would stop printing when reaching 100, could look like:

```
multiple35 = 0
for i in range (15, 100, 15):
    multiple35 += i
    if multiple35 > 100:
        break  # no reason to continue the loop, the sum will never go back below 100
    print(multiple35)
```

Comment: first use of break. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if the final target will exceed the threshold, because in your loop, **when `i=75`, it satisfies the condition `75%15==0` and also satisfies `75<=100`** and since it satisfies both, we let it into the next block which adds 75 to it and gives 150 which exceeds the threshold. The solution is to not even allow a number inside the adding part if when added, crosses the threshold,

There are simpler solutions like above by @Melebius but, I wanted to explain this in the way OP has written

```
multiple35 = 0

for i in range (1, 100):
    if i % 15 == 0 and multiple35+i<=100:
        multiple35 += i
        print(multiple35)
```

Comment: I did try the and clause to the if statement before submitting my original post. It resulted in printing of 150 as well. So, I agree that Melebius' break point is a best solution. Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: @rook2q5 Udaya’s code works for me, you must have made a mistake in your try… However, if you find my solution the best, it would be great if you [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer.

Comment: @rook2q5 You can find the runnable [Python Snippet here](https://repl.it/repls/AdeptLopsidedArea)

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension also here

```
values = [i for i in range(1,100) if i%5==0 if i%3==0]
print("Numbers divisible by 3 and 5:",values)
sum_of_numbers = 0
for i,items in enumerate(values):
    sum_of_numbers = sum_of_numbers+items
    if sum_of_numbers>100:
        break
print(values[:i])
```

Comment: Have not gotten to list comprehension yet, but will add that as a stretch goal today. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple flaws in your logic. I am not going to address them all, but instead suggest an alternate way to solve your issue.

Simply notice that multiples of 3 **and** 5 are exactly the multiples of 15. So there is no need to range over all numbers from 0 to 100.

```
for x in range(15, 100, 15):
    print(x)

# 15
# 30
# 45
# 60
# 75
# 90
```

You also mention that you want to sum all numbers. In python, you can sum over any iterator with `sum`, including a `range`.

```
print(sum(range(15, 100, 15)))

# 315
```

Comment: Thank you Oliver for this feedback. Will give it a try.